# How to generate random lists with no duplicate members?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a=[]
from random import randint as rd
for i in range(42):
    a.append(rd(1,42))
    j=0
    k=len(a)-1
    while(j<=k):
        while(a[i]==a[j]):
            a[i]=rd(1,42)
            j=0
        j=j+1
```

I cannot figure out how to generate entirely unique random lists in python. All the members have to be unique and cannot by any means be the same as any other member of the list

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import random
random.sample(range(100), 10)


In [1715]: random.sample(range(100), 10)
Out[1715]: [66, 48, 97, 5, 39, 67, 78, 96, 71, 19]

In [1716]: random.sample(range(100), 10)
Out[1716]: [50, 89, 60, 69, 81, 86, 27, 94, 4, 62]
```

This will generate a list of 10 random numbers from the range 0 to 99, without duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Use `shuffle` in that case:

```
from random import shuffle

random_numbers = list(range(1, 43))
shuffle(random_numbers)
```

Or, with `randint` as you tried,

```
from random import randint as rd

random_numbers = []
for i in range(42):
    r = rd(1, 42)
    while r in random_numbers:
        r = rd(1, 42)

    random_numbers.append(r)
```